# using IO::Socket::INET receiving and sending message in single prompt

Tags: perl

I have found two types of programs on Website that is based on the IO::Socket::INET module which is receiving and sending the messages via IP address.

Receiving Message Program:

```
use IO::Socket::INET;
my $text;
$MySocket=new IO::Socket::INET->new (LocalPort=>1234,Proto=>'udp');
while(1)
{
    $MySocket->recv($text,128);
    $hostip=$MySocket->peerhost();
    if($text ne '')
    {
        print "\nReceived message from $hostip: $text \n";
        print "Command Output:\n";
        #system("$text");
        print "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print "Client has exited!"; exit 1;
    }
}
```

Sending Message:

```
use IO::Socket::INET;
#Enter Destination IP Message
print "Please Enter the destination IP: \n";
$DestinationIP = <STDIN>;
chomp $DestinationIP;

#Enter message to sent to Server
print "Please Enter your message: \n";
$MySocket=new IO::Socket::INET-> new(PeerPort=>1234,Proto=>1234,Proto=>'udp',PeerAddr=>$DestinationIP);
#$MySocket->send($msg);

while($msg=<STDIN>)
{
    chomp $msg;
    if($msg ne '')
    {
        print "\n Sending $msg";
        if($MySocket->send($msg))
        {
            print "done \n";
            print "\nPlease Enter another message:";
        }
    }
}
```

And my question is how to handle/merge these programs in a single MS-Dos prompt.

For eg:

```
   `Receiving and sending message in Single Prompt.`
```

My sincere apologies, if I have questioned any hypothetical without sense.

Comment: So to get this straight, you just want to run both the receive and Send in a single script? Not needing to run 2 programs but only one?

Comment: @Gerry: Yes. Absolutely this is chat.

Comment: ok, let me post an answer quick. One more question, do you want to use any values from the Received message to send via the send function?

Comment: yes. Its IP address for the particular users. That is reply.

Answer (score 1):

See the Comment next to Line 23 and line 26

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::INET;
my @Destination;
my $text;
my $Receive_Socket=new IO::Socket::INET->new (LocalPort=>1234,Proto=>'udp');
while(1)
{
$Receive_Socket->recv($text,128);
my $hostip=$Receive_Socket->peerhost();
if($text ne '')
{
    print "\nReceived message from $hostip: $text \n";
    print "Command Output:\n";
    #system("$text");
    print "\n";

}
else
{
    print "Client has exited!"; exit 1;
}
push @Destination, $hostip;    # Push the IP Received to where you will send it
}
my $DestinationIP = $Destination[0]; # Here we assign the original $hostip to $DestinationIP
chomp $DestinationIP;

print "Please Enter your message: \n";
my $Send_Socket=new IO::Socket::INET-> new(PeerPort=>1234,Proto=>1234,Proto=>'udp',PeerAddr=>$DestinationIP);
while(my $msg=<STDIN>)
{
chomp $msg;
if($msg ne '')
{
    print "\n Sending $msg";
    if($Send_Socket->send($msg))
    {
        print "done \n";
        print "\nPlease Enter another message:";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: My question is if someone chat with me how can i enter the IP addresses?

Comment: where is the IP address coming from? in the `$text` of the receive? I am unclear on that.

Comment: `$Destination`...?

Comment: Your original script prompts for the destination IP. If you want to carry over the IP from the Received message then you should just post it to Destination. I will edit the script and show you

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now time to break. I will let you know once tested.

Comment: No and its getting hanged while running on server. Need to test more and WIP.